# Populate two different combo boxes using AJAX at a time

Tags: jquery, sql, ajax, combobox

I have 3 combo box: Department, Courses, Activities. The Department combo box which will load all departments from the department table. I need to load the courses in one combo box and activities in another combo box which belong to a department. The table schema is shown below.

```
    Department Table
    ----------------
    | Dept | Name  |
    ----------------
    | 1    | Dept1 |
    | 2    | Dept2 |
    ----------------

    Department Course Table
    ----------------------
    | Cid |Dept | Course |
    ----------------------
    | 1   | 1   | abc    |
    | 2   | 1   | xyz    |
    | 3   | 1   | pqr    |
    | 4   | 2   | bar    |
    | 5   | 2   | foo    |
    ----------------------

    Department Activities Table
    ---------------------------
    | Aid | Dept | Activities |
    ---------------------------
    | 1   | 1    | foo1       |
    | 2   | 1    | foo2       |
    | 3   | 1    | foo3       |
    | 4   | 2    | bar1       |
    | 5   | 2    | bar2       |
    ---------------------------
```

Department combo box will load Dept 1 and Dept 2.
When Dept1 is select the Courses which belong to Dept1 should load in Courses combo box i.e (abc,xyx,pqr) and Activities which which belong to Dept1  should load in Activities combo box i.e (foo1,foo2,foo3).

How to call two functions at the same time in AJAX or jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this :

```
$('#department_combo').change(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "/someUrl/courses",
        success: function(data) {
            // Populate courses with data
        }
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: "/someUrl/activities",
        success: function(data) {
            // Populate activities with data
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: @hungerpain Thanks for your corrections, it typed this snippet too fast. My bad!

Answer (score 0):

Since the activities and courses are department specific I would do one ajax request that returns the courses and activites for a specific department in an JSON object that may look something like this when the uses selected dept 1:

```
{
courses : [
    {cid:1,course:'abc'},
    {cid:2,course:'xyz'},
    {cid:3,course:'prq'}],
activities : [
    {aid:1,activity:'foo1'},
    {aid:2,activity:'foo2'},
    {aid:3,activity:'foo3'}]
}
```

and this when the user selected dep2:

```
{
courses : [
    {cid:4,course:'bar'},
    {cid:5,course:'foo'}],
activities : [
    {aid:4,activity:'bar1'},
    {aid:5,activity:'bar2'}]
}
```

so on the change event of your department dropdown your event handler would make your ajax request and fill the activity and course dropdown with the results returned from the server.

```
$('#department').change(function(){
    $.ajax(
       url: 'urlToYourServersideCode',
       success: function(coursesAndActvities){
           var courses = coursesAndActivies.courses,
               activites = coursesAndActivies.activities,
               sCourses='',
               sActivies = '';
           for(var idx = 0;idx < activities.length;++idx){          
               sActivities+= '<option value="'+ activities[idx].aid +'">' + activities[idx].activity +'</option>';

           }
           for(var idx = 0;idx < courses.length;++idx){         
               sCourses+= '<option value="'+ courses[idx].aid +'">' + courses[idx].course+'</option>';

           }
           $('#activities).empty().append(sActivities);
           $('#courses).empty().append(sCourses);
       }
 );
});
```